# Regex conditionals (only if string exists)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get some redirection rules ready with regex replacement.. Here's what I have

http://example.com/12345/this-is-the-headline

should be rewritten to

http://example.com/news/this-is-the-headline

so far so good. This is currently done by:

`([0-9]{4,7})/([a-z0-9-]+)(.*)`

and replaced by

`news/$2`

This works for quite a while now. Unfortunately some new things come into place and I need to filter these cases out.

http://example.com/newterm/12345/this-is-the-headline

should not be rewritten. I know I can catch this with something like

`(?!newterm/)` in my pattern but I'm not sure how to do the "only if" part in the replacement.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `^/?([0-9]{4,7})/([a-z0-9-]+)(.*)`?

Comment: I thought I had tried that already. Must have mistyped it. But that worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to anchor the pattern at the start to only match the number subpart at the start of the input:

```
^/?([0-9]{4,7})/([a-z0-9-]+)(.*)
^
```

The `/?`  will match an optional `/`.